# Make a phone call when click on a phone number String

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a phone number like this: `025639879`. I got it from the database as a `String`.
Now i want to make a Phone call exactly when the user click on that number, i have tried to do like this:

```
NSString *phoneNumber=[@"tel://"stringByAppendingString:myAppGlobalVariables.telephoneTheme];


NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>Téléphone:%@</body
</html>",phoneNumber];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

What i got in my app is this:

```
Téléphone:tel://025639879
```

Am i missing something? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. skip the tel:// and make your webview recognize phone numbers as links (there will be false positives so be careful with this).
2. make a `<a href="tel://number">number</a>` link:

   `NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p>Téléphone:<a href=\"tel://%@\">%@</a></p></body></html>", myAppGlobalVariables.telephoneTheme, myAppGlobalVariables.telephoneTheme];
   [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];`

Comment: Can you please be more specific, i try to modify as you say: `NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body></body><p>Téléphone:<a href=tel://%@>%@</a></p></body></html>", myAppGlobalVariables.telephoneTheme, myAppGlobalVariables.telephoneTheme];[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myAppGlobalVariables.telephoneTheme]];`

Comment: Okay, that looks fine, but why when i click on it in the simulator, nothing is performed, i was waiting a prompt asking me wether i want to dial the phone number. How can i detect the click (i am still testing on the simulator)

Comment: There will be no prompt for this. If you want a prompt you will have to make your own implementation with an UIAlertView. Something like: `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = [request URL];
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"alert"]) {UIAlertView * alert...` and the link will be "alert://" instead of "tel://".

Comment: telprompt: also works for getting a prompt (and automatically returning to the app after the call is finished).